# Metodo que usa Viewbag en todas las vistas ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

En mi `_Layout` tengo un `ViewBag` que muestra X saldo de una tabla, esto se muestra al estar en el controlador `Home`:

**VISTA**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Double temp;
    Boolean isOk = Double.TryParse(TempData["SaldoGV"].ToString(), out temp);
    Int32 value = isOk ? (Int32)temp : 0;

    Double temp2;
    Boolean isOk2 = Double.TryParse(TempData["CantidadRegalia"].ToString(), out temp2);
    Int32 value2 = isOk2 ? (Int32)temp2 : 0;
}
@using BoldReports.Mvc;
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["usuario"] as string))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("CerrarSesion", "Login");
            }
            AsignadorMenus(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            TempData["SaldoGV"] = ADO.SaldoPorUsuario(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            TempData["CantidadRegalia"] = ADO.DineroRegalias(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            TempData["PromedioProductos"] = ADO.PromedioProductos(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            return View(_menus); 
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si navego a otra vista (por ende otro controlador) me salta el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es obvio, para manejar esto puedo agregar los mismas líneas:

```
TempData["SaldoGV"] = ADO.SaldoPorUsuario(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                TempData["CantidadRegalia"] = ADO.DineroRegalias(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                TempData["PromedioProductos"] = ADO.PromedioProductos(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                return View(_menus);
```

en los demás controladores, pero seria muy redundante, hay alguna manera mas practica de solo declarar estas líneas "una sola vez" y que tome el dato de ahí? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes generar un controlador global o filtro que del que hereden tus controladores donde necesies esos datos y en el evento OnActionExecuting lo asignas al TempData, por ejemplo

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Session["usuario"] != null)
            {
                TempData["SaldoGV"] = ADO.SaldoPorUsuario(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                TempData["CantidadRegalia"] = ADO.DineroRegalias(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                TempData["PromedioProductos"] = ADO.PromedioProductos(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

y en tu controlador que no se como se llama pero le llamare AlgoController simplemente lo heredas

```
public class AlgoController : MyController{
   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["usuario"] as string))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CerrarSesion", "Login");
        }
        AsignadorMenus(Session["usuario"].ToString());
        return View(_menus);
    } 
}
```

asi ya no necesitarias repetir esas lineas en cada metodo, el detalle seria ese, que cada metodo que tuvieras en el controlador al heredar pasaria por ese metodo y lo ejecutaria, lo que podrias validar si lo hicieras como un filtro, tal como:

```
public class UserDataFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           if (Session["usuario"] != null)
                {
                    TempData["SaldoGV"] = ADO.SaldoPorUsuario(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                    TempData["CantidadRegalia"] = ADO.DineroRegalias(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                    TempData["PromedioProductos"] = ADO.PromedioProductos(Session["usuario"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

y este lo podrias utilizar especificando solo los metodos en los que lo necesites:

```
public class AlgoController{
       [UserDataFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["usuario"] as string))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("CerrarSesion", "Login");
            }
            AsignadorMenus(Session["usuario"].ToString());
            return View(_menus);
        } 
    }
```

Espero te sirva al menos de referencia o como idea.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!!